# new pages link to menubar, html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a website for our small society.
My question is how I can link new pages from navigation bar menu.
What I can do now is to link from navigation bar to a new page.
what I want is that the new page can be shown under the navbar on the same page.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: do internal linking in html

Comment: Thanks! I think I need to reformula my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use internal link in html

Do you need like this,
     <html>
        <head>
          </head>
           <body>
                <p><a href="#color">Link to color </a></p>
                <p><a href="#image">Link to image</a></p>

                <h1 id="color">Color 1</h1>
                <p>Text </p>

                <h1 id="image">Image 2</h1>
                <p>Text </p>
            </body>
        </html>
```

you can also refer a link:

https://jsfiddle.net/17d80ym3/15/

Comment: Thanks. I need to reformula my question. say I have navbar if I cklick on one item("about")in the menu, I want this "about" page can appear under the navbar on the samepage instead it goes(links) to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

your page should be something like this:->>

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Internal Linking</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="home">
<h1>Home</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

    Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

    Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
</div>

<div id="about">
<h1>About</h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

    Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

    Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
</div>

<div id="contact">
<h1>Contact</h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

    Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

    Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec erat massa. Praesent rutrum eros ac odio fringilla rutrum. Aliquam risus lacus, porttitor sit amet convallis non, ultricies eleifend magna. Nullam quis tincidunt neque. Quisque mattis nibh at urna maximus, non commodo ligula luctus. Nunc tincidunt enim ac hendrerit rhoncus. Nullam iaculis laoreet dignissim. Integer at lectus iaculis, maximus orci quis, accumsan nisi. Pellentesque eu enim lacus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin ex. Curabitur efficitur ut risus nec eleifend. Mauris luctus, libero nec dictum congue, orci elit laoreet neque, ultricies tincidunt ligula sem vitae ipsum. Nullam condimentum ante a dapibus porta.

Cras viverra placerat porttitor. Aenean id iaculis diam. Aliquam blandit dapibus risus, ac finibus nibh rutrum et. Duis vitae varius nulla. Duis pulvinar a nibh sit amet commodo. Etiam venenatis ornare euismod. Nulla id urna at nisi semper elementum vitae non felis. Proin mollis metus quis lorem gravida, in sollicitudin mi lacinia. Fusce egestas vestibulum est, id fringilla metus.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**try this code...This will do what you want...**

Comment: Thanks. I need to reformula my question. say I have navbar if I cklick on one item("about")in the menu, I want this "about" page can appear under the navbar on the samepage instead it goes(links) to a new page.